# Azure DevOps Extension point for Hub in Overview section

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

I am looking to add a web hub to Azure Devops through an extension that I would place under the "Overview" section, next to the Dashboards and Wiki links.  Looking through the documentation for the extension points, there doesn't seem to be one listed for that particular heading.  I believe that that is perhaps an oversight in the documentation
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/devops/extend/reference/targets/overview

Any ideas on what the current full list of extension points is? or where they may be documented?

Answer (score 1):

Just worked through this with one of my developers and we found out that in the contributions section of your vss.extension.json file you need to set the "targets" as follows:

[Home-Hub_Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6cTw.png)